# Use existing sqlite database in flutter app

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I'm new to dart and flutter, and I'm trying to create an app that uses an existing sqlite database. I've included the asset in my pubspec.yaml file. When I run the app, none of the data in my existing database is shown. It looks like it is creating a new table each time. Here is my code to copy the table.

```
Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);

    var exists = await databaseExists(path);

    if (!exists) {
      print("Creating a new copy from assets");

      // Make sure the parent directory exists
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
        print("Creating directory");
      } catch (_) {
        print('Error creating Directory');
      }

      // Copy from asset
      print("Copying DB");
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "notes.db"));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      // Write and flush the bytes written
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      print('DB has been copied');
    } else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
  }
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're calling onCreate in the callback for openDatabase which will create a new table I believe...have a look at the API docs: https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/openDatabase.html